# Unexpected token error using Swagger annotations

Tags: java, grails, swagger

I am testing Swagger annotations using a code I copied from the Swagger-core Github.

The code excerpt I am testing comes from the static class SimpleOperations from [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-jaxrs2/src/test/java/io/swagger/v3/jaxrs2/annotations/examples/ExamplesTest.java#L446) (line 446)

In my code, it looks like this:

```
(...) 

@Controller("/")
class IntegratorWebController {

    def convoyWebService

    @Operation(
            operationId = "subscribe",
            description = "subscribes a client to updates relevant to the requestor's account, as identified by the input token.  The supplied url will be used as the delivery address for response payloads",
            parameters = {
                @Parameter(in = ParameterIn.PATH, name = "subscriptionId", required = true,
                        schema = @Schema(implementation = Convoy.class),
                        style = ParameterStyle.SIMPLE, example = "example",
                        examples = {
                            @ExampleObject(name = "subscriptionId_1", value = "12345",
                                    summary = "Subscription number 12345", externalValue = "Subscription external value 1"),
                            @ExampleObject(name = "subscriptionId_2", value = "54321",
                                    summary = "Subscription number 54321", externalValue = "Subscription external value 2")
                        })
            },
            responses = {
                @ApiResponse(
                        description = "test description",
                        content = @Content(
                                mediaType = "*/*",
                                schema = @Schema(
                                        type = "string",
                                        format = "uuid",
                                        description = "the generated UUID",
                                        accessMode = Schema.AccessMode.READ_ONLY,
                                        example = "Schema example"
                                ),
                                examples = {
                                    @ExampleObject(name = "Default Response", value = "SubscriptionResponse",
                                            summary = "Subscription Response Example", externalValue = "Subscription Response value 1")
                                }
                        ))
            })

    def saveOrUpdateActivity(){
        def result = [error:[]]
        def status = OK

   (...)
```

The only difference is that I replaced ExamplesTest.SubscriptionResponse.class to a class that exists on my code.

I am using

- io.swagger.core.v3, swagger-annotations version 2.1.2
- Java 11
- Grails 4.0.2

I am getting:

```
IntegratorWebController.groovy: 28: unexpected token: @ @ line 28, column 2.
        @Operation(
    ^
```

At the IDE it looks like this:

[image]

Javadoc says that @Parameter can be used independently in Operation or at method level to add a parameter to the operation, even if not bound to any method parameter. So the example is sound.

What is wrong?

Tks!

Answer (score 1):

Because I am coding in Groovy, I have to use [] instead of {} for the array of @Parameters and @ExampleObject.

The correct code looks like this:

```
    @Post(uri="/saveOrUpdateActivity", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Operation(
            operationId = "subscribe",
            description = "subscribes a client to updates relevant to the requestor's account, as identified by the input token.  The supplied url will be used as the delivery address for response payloads",
            parameters = [
                @Parameter(in = ParameterIn.PATH, name = "subscriptionId", required = true,
                        schema = @Schema(implementation = Convoy.class),
                        style = ParameterStyle.SIMPLE, example = "example",
                        examples = [
                            @ExampleObject(name = "subscriptionId_1", value = "12345",
                                    summary = "Subscription number 12345", externalValue = "Subscription external value 1"),
                            @ExampleObject(name = "subscriptionId_2", value = "54321",
                                    summary = "Subscription number 54321", externalValue = "Subscription external value 2")
                        ])
            ],
            responses = [
                @ApiResponse(
                        description = "test description",
                        content = @Content(
                                mediaType = "*/*",
                                schema = @Schema(
                                        type = "string",
                                        format = "uuid",
                                        description = "the generated UUID",
                                        accessMode = Schema.AccessMode.READ_ONLY,
                                        example = "Schema example"
                                ),
                                examples = [
                                    @ExampleObject(name = "Default Response", value = "SubscriptionResponse",
                                            summary = "Subscription Response Example", externalValue = "Subscription Response value 1")
                                ]
                        ))
            ])
```